# UWP app is crashing in release mode when using Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am using **Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms** for taking signature. following code is working perfectly fine when i am debugging it. but app is crashing in release build. **The app is crashing when i am restoring the points from a property.**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public IEnumerable<Point> Points { get; private set; }

        private SignaturePadView sigview;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var x = new StackLayout();


             sigview = new SignaturePadView()
            {
                HeightRequest = 320,
                WidthRequest = 240,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                CaptionText = "Caption this",
                CaptionTextColor = Color.Black,
                ClearText = "Clear!",
                ClearTextColor = Color.Black,
                SignatureLineColor = Color.Black,
                StrokeColor = Color.Black,
                StrokeWidth = 2
            };

            var btn1 = new Button(){ Text = "save"};
            var btn2 = new Button(){Text = "Restore"};

            btn1.Clicked += Btn1_Clicked;
            btn2.Clicked += Btn2_Clicked;

           x.Children.Add(sigview);
           x.Children.Add(btn1);
           x.Children.Add(btn2);

            this.Content = x;

        }

        private void Btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.sigview.Clear();


                this.sigview.Points = this.Points;


        }

        private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Points = this.sigview.Points;
        }
    }
```

**Exception Log**

> ComTypeMarshalling_MissingInteropData    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4846fa    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x48419f    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x483ead    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x483e37    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4837d1    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x48375c    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x483702    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x4e5701    at
>   ProteusMMX.UWP!+0x23942e7    at
>   Xamarin.Controls.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__1(Foundation.Point[]
>   s)    at SharedLibrary!+0x3c1adf    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x39b50e    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x39b56b    at
>   ProteusMMX.UWP!+0x1e1a54c    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x574410    at
>   SharedLibrary!+0x574509    at
>   ProteusMMX.UWP!+0x1d0dc6c    at
>   ProteusMMX.UWP!+0x1d0dd3c    at
>   ProteusMMX.UWP!+0x1d0dd9d    at
>   Xamarin.Controls.Extensions.AddStrokes(UI.Input.Inking.InkPresenter
>   inkPresenter, Collections.Generic.IList
>   strokes, UI.Color color, Single width)    at
>   Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePadCanvasView.LoadPoints(Foundation.Point[]
>   loadedPoints)    at
>   SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadCanvasRenderer.OnPointsSpecified(Object
>   sender, Forms.SignaturePadCanvasView.PointsEventArgs e)    at
>   SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadCanvasView.SetSignaturePoints(Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   points)    at
>   SignaturePad.Forms.SignaturePadView.set_Points(Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   value)

Comment: have you tried capturing the exception that causes the crash?

Comment: Yes. I shared below @Jason

Comment: I'd try reporting it here: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad/issues